# I backed up to itunes but it didn't transfer to my new iphone

Tags: itunes, restore, iphone

I did a backup of my iPhone 4 to iTunes in anticipation of getting a new iPhone 5S.

When I did the restore to my new iPhone after I got the new phone, it didn't give me the latest data that was on the old phone.

What happened? Is that data gone forever since I no longer have that old phone?

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent, you will need to provide more information to get a meaningful answer.  What is missing, songs? Application data, contacts? What iOS were you using on the iPhone 4 etc.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the data backed up it should still be available. That being said, it depends on the amount of data you decided to back up. Also make sure to use the same iCloud ID since you might have started to use the iCloud for backups and not you PC.

Both Backup and Restore procedures for iCloud and iTunes is listed on [Apple Support website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766).

Comment: I didn't back up to iCloud, never enough space. The restore I got was from a backup I did over a year ago, including old settings and apps I'd deleted over this last year. Email wants me to set up my old account that is no longer active.

Comment: @Shannon I see in that case the apps and data related to your old account is unfortunately lost. Since apple has yet to provide the method to merge old non apple id accounts with the iCloud there is no known way to associate your purchases.